# Function and density distribution of a random variable (Change of Variables)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \mathcal U(-4; 3)$

Let's define $Y$ like this:

$$Y = \begin{cases} 2X-8 & : X\leqslant -3 \\[0.5ex] X+1 & : X> -3 \end{cases}$$

What is the procedure for finding the density and the distribution of $Y$? This is the first task I ever encountered of this kind and I have no clue where I am supposed to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given: $$\begin{align}f_X(x) & = \frac 1 7 \;[-4< x< 3]
\\[2ex] Y & = \begin{cases} 2X-8 & : X\leqslant -3 \\[0.5ex] X+1 & : X> -3 \end{cases}
\\[2ex] \therefore X & = \begin{cases} \frac{Y}{2}+4  & : Y\leqslant -12 \\ Y-1 & : Y>-2\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

A quick sketch show we are dealing with two positive sloped line segments with a step discontinuity at $X=-3$.

Other than that discontinuity in the piecewise function, a simple change of variables transformation will suffice.   $f_Y(y) = f_X(y^{-1}(x)) \lvert\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d y}\rvert$

$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \tfrac 1 7 \left\lvert \tfrac 1 2\tfrac{\mathrm d (y+8)}{\mathrm d y}\right\rvert  & : -16< y\leqslant -12 \\[1ex] \tfrac 1 7 \left\lvert \tfrac{\mathrm d (y-1)}{\mathrm d y} \right\rvert & : -2< y < 4\\ 0 & : \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think you made a mistake for $Fx(x)$ shouldn't it be $(x+4)/7$ on an open interval?

Comment: $f_X(x)=\frac 1 7\;[-4< x< 3]$ is the probability density function, @kjanko.  $F_X(x) = \frac{x+4}{7}\;[-4<x< 3]$ is the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: I might've made a translation error :| Thanks for the answer, I won't be a further pain I'll try to figure it out on my own :)